# How Hyperledger Fabric ledger size impacts performance?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The ledger size stored in `/var/hyperledger/production` is increasing day by day. For example after 3-4 years, the size can be in Terabytes. Is there any -

1. Performance issues when doing r/w transactions?
2. Way to cut some blocks and reduce the size of data and still maintain the validity of the chain?
3. How much ledger size (in GB or TB) that Hyperledger Fabric can tolerate the performance?
4. Any data archival or off chain strategy?

Answer (score 0):

for your question,I try to find the answer in the source code,and a little bit of answer

1、for your first question:

in fabric v1.4.2 source code `commom/ledger/blockfile_mgr.go`,method `getTransactionByID`is used as tx query,according to this method,final this method will call method `getTxLoc`, we can know when we query a tx,we need first to get block which the tx locate,we can find this block quick with index(I don’t have a deep understanding of the indexing mechanism，but I think it is helpful in performance)

2、for your second and third question:

in fabric v1.4.2 source code `commom/ledger/blockfile_mgr.go`,method `addBlock` is used as add block to blockfile(which located at /var/hyperledger/production/...blockfile_000000),we can find some usefull information in this method:

```
//Determine if we need to start a new file since the size of this block
//exceeds the amount of space left in the current file
//default value of maxBlockfileSize is 64 * 1024 * 1024
if currentOffset+totalBytesToAppend > mgr.conf.maxBlockfileSize {
    mgr.moveToNextFile()
    currentOffset = 0
}
```

It means when blockfile bigger than 64 * 1024 * 1024,It will create a new blockfile

3、for your last question

I have not found related information

hope these are helpful for you.